# Soft hyphens or hyphenation hints in TextBlocks

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows 8 style hub page with tiles that contain big text in TextBlocks. In some localizations, the text is too long for one line and needs to be wrapped. Per default wrapping only occurs at spaces and hyphens. But sometimes even single words are too long and need to be wrapped, too.

[image]

<sup>image description: 3 blue tiles: "Text", "Several BREAK short BREAK words", "Antidisesta BREAK blishmenta BREAK rianism"</sup>

I want the wrapping within words to be typographically correct, i.e. with hyphens and at the right positions (not simply after the last letter that fits into the line).

In WPF, I solved a similar issue by putting [soft hyphens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) into the text, as hyphenation hints.

> In computing and typesetting, a soft hyphen [..] is a kind of hyphen used to specify a place in text where a hyphenated break is allowed without forcing a line break in an inconvenient place if the text is re-flowed.

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work in the [XAML framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime_XAML_Framework). They are simply ignored. [Zero-width spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), too.

Is there some way to make soft hyphens work? Or some other way to insert hyphenation hints?

**Note**: I know that I could hard-code the hyphens/breaks by writing "Antidises-tablish-mentaria-nism", but that would tie the string to a specific (size of a) TextBlock and create superflous non-breaking mid-word hyphens in other TextBlocks. I want to avoid this.

Comment: (The image is not showing for me. It seems there's [a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186466) with stack.imgur.com)

Comment: @dtb: Hmpf. OK, added a textual description, too.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @karlingen I don't remember, but I probably did not solve the issue. I have not worked on this app or any other Windows Store / UWP app in a long time.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus I see. Thanks for getting back to me though. And it seems like there's an open feature request for this: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4068

Answer (score 0):

Soft hyphens would usually be implemented using "U+00AD" but these are ignored in WinRT.  You could use the RichTextBlock with the "-" encoding.

Comment: What does _the "-" encoding_ mean?

Comment: What do you mean with "_use the RichTextBlock with the "-" encoding._"? Use a RichTextBlock and insert a soft hyphen into an inline element, e.g. a paragraph? No, that does **not** work. Down voted until you clarify...